# Comma misplaced on RightToLeft label

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to partially recreate the Windows 10 calculator but have run into some trouble. I have a code that looks like this for when the user enters a comma:

```
if (label_number.Text != null)
{
    label_number.Text += ",";
}
else
{
    label_number.Text = "0,";
}
```

So if the user enters the comma while the string is null I want the string to read out "0," but it only adds the "," to the label. And when I add a comma to a number, it comes out like this ",07839" instead of "07839,". Why is this happening? Like the title says my label is RightToLeft, but this also happens when that option is false.

Edit, here is the entire MouseClick EventHandler
'''

```
    private void MouseClickEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = (sender as Label);
        
        // Left click
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (obj.Name == "button_quit") // Quit
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_minimize") // Minimize
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_c") // Reset calc
            {
                label_input.Text = String.Empty;
                label_number.Text = String.Empty;
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_ce") // Clear number
            {
                label_number.Text = String.Empty;
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_delete") // Delete
            {
                if (label_number.Text.Length == 1)
                {
                    label_number.Text = String.Empty;
                }
                else if (label_number.Text.Length > 1)
                {
                    label_number.Text = label_number.Text.Remove(label_number.Text.Length - 1, 1);
                }
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_divide" || obj.Name == "button_multiply" || obj.Name == "button_subtract" || obj.Name == "button_add") // / * - +
            {
                switch (obj.Name)
                {
                    case "button_divide":

                        break;

                    case "button_multiply":

                        break;

                    case "button_subtract":

                        break;

                    case "button_add":

                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_comma") // Comma
            {
                if (label_number.Text != String.Empty)
                {
                    label_number.Text += ",";
                }
                else
                {
                    label_number.Text = "0,";
                }
            }
            else if (obj.Name == "button_equals") // Calculate equation
            {

            }
            else // Number input
            {
                if (label_number.Text.Length < 13)
                {
                    if (obj.Name != "button_0")
                    {
                        if (label_number.Text.Length == 1 && label_number.Text == "0")
                        {
                            label_number.Text = obj.Name[obj.Name.Length - 1].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label_number.Text += obj.Name[obj.Name.Length - 1].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label_number.Text += obj.Name[obj.Name.Length - 1].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

'''

Comment: The Text property is never null. You should check with string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace or string.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: I think you are running this code multiple times, so first time it add `,` because Text will be empty and then it will again come in `if` again to your number becomes ,o7839. it is never going in else

Comment: @viveknuna I'm not sure I understand? Can you rephrase?

Comment: @Steve I changed null to String.Empty

Comment: @MacA put a breakpoint and try to reproduce the scenario

Comment: @MacA you are calling this code inside some event handler right? Then please post the event handler code. As is it is difficult to understand the conditions that leads to this code.

Comment: @Steve Updated the post and added the MouseClick event handler